# Remove spaces from matrix output

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I want to remove spaces from the matrix:

```
my_list = range(10, -11, -2)  # שאלה 3 בבוחן
import numpy as np

c = np.array(my_list)
cutoff = 0
c[c < cutoff] = -1
print("new arr is:", *c,sep=' ')

import numpy as np

list_of_lists=[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[4,5,6]
matrix=np.array(list_of_lists)
print("Row 2 in matrix:",matrix[1])
import numpy as np
broad=np.full((1,3),2)
matrix=matrix*broad
    # list_of_list=matrix.tolist()
    # lst1= tr(list_of_list)
    # lst2 = lst1.replace("","").replace(",","")
    # lst3=lst2[:9]+""+lst2[9:17]+""+lst2[17:]
print("Broadcasting:",matrix)
```

The matrix print is:

```
[[ 2  4  6]
 [ 6  4  2]
 [ 8 10 12]]
```

And I want

```
[[2  4  6]
 [6  4  2]
 [8 10 12]]
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numpy matrix is pretty-printed for your viewing pleasure.  You can force your desired output by converting it to a python list-of-lists and deleting the commas:

```
print_me = str(list(map(list, matrix))).replace(',', '')
print(print_me)
```

which prints:

```
[[2 4 6] [6 4 2] [8 10 12]]
```

Comment: can i make it look like a matrix tho?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the repr() function which returns the printable representation of the string.

```
print('Broadcasting:', repr(str(matrix)).replace('\\n ', '').replace('  ', ' '))
```

This prints:

```
Broadcasting: '[[ 2 4 6][ 6 4 2][ 8 10 12]]'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in option to remove the spaces from the first numbers. However, you can use [`np.array2string`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array2string.html) to convert the matrix to a string and then modify the string:

```
import numpy as np
import re
s = re.sub(r'\[\s*', '[', np.array2string(matrix))
print(s)
```

Output:

```
[[2  4  6]
 [6  4  2]
 [8 10 12]]
```